# Prove f is Onto

Tags: group-theory

Let $f: ( \mathbb{Z}_6, +)\rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}_{12}, +)$ be defined by $f(x)=2x$. Is $f$ onto?

I know that onto means: If $b \in B$ there is an $a\in A$ so that $f(a)=b$.

I made a chart:

$$x   | \;\; \,\,\,   1 \;\; 2 \;\; 3 \;\; 4 \;\; 5$$

$$f(x) | \;\; 2  \;\;4 \;\; 6 \;\; 8 \;\; 10$$

$x\in \mathbb{Z}_6$ and $f(x)$ exists in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$

I don't think that $f$ is onto because there is not a value from $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ that has a mapping from $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Am I on the right track? I am having a hard time understanding the definition. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You missed $0$ in your table, but otherwise you are on the right track.

Looking at the track, did you list all elements in $\mathbb Z_{12}$ or not? If yes, the function is onto, if not it is not because it doesn't take those values...

Comment: I didn't list all the elements in Z12. What I did was plug the values from Z6 into f(x)=2x. (Except 0, I left that off.)

Comment: @user102839 .... and you got $0,2,4,6,8, 10$ in your list. This is what we call the image of $f$. As these are NOT all the elements in $\mathbb Z_{12}$, it means $f$ is not onto.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Notice the Image $f$ consists of all multiples of $2$ mod $6$. Hence,

$$ Imf \subset \mathbb{Z}_{12} \; \; \; \implies Imf \neq\mathbb{Z}_{12} \implies f \; \text{is not surjective} $$